# Check another Dictionary if all values are false

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

Im battling to figure out the best solution for this as I don't have a frame of reference and I'm still learning.
I have 3 Stages in my game that are stored in a Dictionary which look something like this:

```
var stages = ["Stage_01": ["Level_01": true, "Level_02": false],
              "Stage_02": ["Level_03": true, "Level_04": false],
              "Stage_03": ["Level_05": true, "Level_06": false]]
```

I created a function to loop through them to see if they are set to true or false. If they are true then they just return the level and thats that. If they are false it must move on to the next level.
If all the levels are false then I want it to load the next stage and this is where my knowledge is lacking, in layman terms I basically need it to just back to the top of the function in order to iterate through all the stages which clearly won't work with my current logic.
Any direction would be appreciated.

```
func loadNextLevel() -> String {
  var falseCounter = 0
  var stageNumber = 1
  var loadLevel = ""

  if var stage = stages["Stage_0\(stageNumber)"] as? Dictionary<String, Bool> {
    for (level, value) in stage {
      if value == true {
             // Set it to false and update the value then return the level
             stage[level] = false
             stages.updateValue(stage, forKey: "Stage_0\(stageNumber)")
             return level
      } else {
             falseCounter += 1
      }

      if falseCounter == 5 {
                //All levels are done, load next stage
                if self.stageNumber < 4 {
                    self.stageNumber += 1
                    loadNextLevel()
                } else {
                    // reset all the levels back to true and start again
                }

    return loadLevel
}
```

Comment: I think you could just use an array of dictionaries and each element (dictionary) in your array can represent a stage. You could also use the same approach for the levels and just use a 2D Bool array

Comment: Just a few small comments: better use the stageNumber as Index (it might one day be >= 10 or you might want to translate "Stage"). You do not have to compare value to true (if value { } is enough).

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok, but then what happens when none of them return a String and I reset all the values back to true and need to start the function all over again?

Comment: I didn't understand your logic and question. I don't even know what true/false means there (true == not cleared ?? )  but a dictionary it is not needed here.

Comment: I'm not sure about the logic either - should true and false say if you still have to play that level or something similar? Also you will probably need two loops, the first iterating through stages and the next one inside it iterating through the levels.

Comment: If the level is true it means its available to be played. Once its been played its set to false. Once all the levels have been played (they are all false), they get reset to start again (all set back to true) and then need to start iterating through again.

Comment: Edit your question and add that info there not in comments

Comment: It is in there.

Comment: you should really use `Structs` or `Classes` for data like this, it would make everything much easier